# KeyError: Index(['StateAbb'], dtype='object')

Tags: python, pandas

Because of the error, I cannot drop the duplicates using following code:

```
cc.drop_duplicates(subset="StateAbb")
```

How can I sole the issue?

Comment: `StateAbb` is the index , you can't de-duplicate index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StateAbb is the index , you can't de-duplicate index .
you can do this :

```
cc = cc.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset="StateAbb").set_index('StateAbb')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and boolean NOT (`~`):

```
cc = cc[~cc.index.duplicated()]
```